# Calculator - Online Cash desk

Tags: javascript, php, calculator

title is as always weird, but it's basically just what I need.

I am going to help out during a christmas market here in germany and sell some stuff. 
I am not good in math and secondly something like a cash system would make the work even faster for everyone.

[image: Calculator]

This is what it should be like. Products an their prices always stay the same. If the customer wants more than 1 of the product I want to write a straight number into the multiply field. And then get the result of each product at the end. And a field with all results together in case the customer wants a couple of different products.

Now I tell him the price and if customer says yes, then he will give me the money. 
I write that into the "what customer gives me" field and then want to know how many he get's back. (105-90,80)

Then clear everything so I can start from new with a new customer. 
If it is possible to do everything without buttons (all results changing automatically) then that would be even better.

It's all easier as described here. A "simple" calculator made in 10 min. At least that's what my friends told me. Javascript or PHP. The problem is, I am a noob in both of them and have no clue how to do this.

My question would be if there is anyone willing to explain how to do this or maybe even having those 10 min to write something like a template for me. 
I would be more than thankful.

Thank you everyone!

Greetings

M.G.

PS: If someone knows an App or a calculator that does already exist with those functions, that would help aswell!

I forgot to say one important thing: This shall work on an iPad if possible. 
That's why the online version.

Comment: Are you just wanting the data to output in to an element on that page?

Comment: Also, how are you getting the data for the products, or will you be hard coding the into the page?

Comment: The data for the products are always constant. I have a list with them products and their prices. So hard coding.  And yes, the results shall show somewhere on the page (like in the picture)

Comment: I'll put a fiddle together to show you.

Comment: Thank you Ross. That'd be great.

Comment: C'mon, take this as an opportunity to practice some mental maths ;-]

Comment: @MatthiasGies I'd added one as an answer.

Comment: This smells as homework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this. It's only basic, but itshould provide you with what you need.
You have to store the value for the product as a float in the `data.value` attr of the `td`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Fr9de/1/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Ross, this works perfectly. Is there any way to make a clear button though? I will have like 50 different products and to clear every field would take too long if there are many customers.

Comment: What would you want the button to do? i.e. Do you not want the grandTotal to automatically update?

Comment: To clear all boxes where I can enter something. In your example this would be the amount.

Comment: I've changed the link to show this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Fr9de/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Fr9de/2/ ...To see the difference between my revisions just change the /2/ to /1/ or remove it completely. Please could you accept and upvote the answer? :) If you have any more questions let me know. Cheers.

Comment: It works great. I've tried to work the rest out myself. But can't get it. Once I have the grandTotal result, I want to write into another box how much I get from the customer and then subtract grandTotal from that number. Like "money"-grandTotal

Comment: This is what I mean: http://i.imagebanana.com/img/2eby080h/example.JPG  I Write something into this "In" Box and then it shall subtract grandTotal from what's in the "In" box.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Fr9de/3/ I've added that functionality into this fiddle. Please excuse the html mark up and lack of styling.

Comment: Ross - ur the best. I'd send you some of the german christmas marked sweets if I could. Exactly what I needed and it will help all of us. No problem with the styling, I can do that myself. Only can't write scripts. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's absolutely fine. Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a spreadsheet for that.
You can use Microsoft Excel or OpenOffice Calc or Google Spreadsheet.

Simply copy this example
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Amac8Gfn8i9HdDlybTBPQUl5VTZheUNRME1uRXpSd3c&usp=sharing

Comment: I thought of that. But then there is the question how to do this "clear all" button without losing everything?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the same thing I need, but there is no clear all button which is important in this case and it would be hard to handle on a mobile device.